# HttpWebRequest (401) Unauthorized with correct credentials

Tags: c#, webrequest

I'm having trouble getting a WebRequest to pass authentication when trying to download a file from a URL. I have verified that, hitting the url directly and being prompted with a username / password form, my credentials go through just fine and the file is downloaded to my computer.

However, when using a WebRequest (with a proxy) i'm getting a (401) Authentication failed.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";

WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("myProxyAddress:myProxyPort");
proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
request.Proxy = proxy;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

It's definitely passing proxy auth as i was a getting a 407 before. I've tried a myriad of settings such as setting PreAuthenticate to true, UseDefaultCredentials to false etc but to no avail.

Is there something i'm missing here? Could it be down to the type of auth the 3rd party url is requiring?

Comment: Without knowing more about the service on the other end of that web request its hard to say ... but it sounds like your network credential is either being rejected or is not in the right place / format that the server is expecting on their end.

Comment: It may well be a case of contacting the 3rd party and simply asking.

Comment: watch it using wireshark or something, probably using a different auth mechanism than you'd expect.